# Azure Devops CI pipeline not showing .Net option to build a project under Agent tasks

Tags: .net, build, azure-pipelines

I am practicing Azure CI/CD pipeline and setting up a build pipeline. I was following the tutorial on which has a project in .Net Core while my project is in .Net 4.72. For creating a task for Restore Nuget and Build I could not find option for ".Net".  I only found .Net Core.  Nevertheless I selected the .Net Core to complete the CI pipeline and when I did the build I got the below error which seem to be due .Net Core version.

[image]

MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.408\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.408\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [**Use .NET Core task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) to specify the version of .NET Core required in your project.

This task will acquire the specified .NET Core version from the Internet or the tools cache and add it to the PATH.

Then, in the subsequent .NET tasks (such as **`dotnet restore`**, **`dotnet build`**, **`dotnet test`**, etc..), the specified .NET Core version will be used for your project.

Comment: My project based on .Net 4.72, so I can't use .Net Core 6